# Картинка не отображается в ImageWiew

Tags: android, webview, imageview

Загружаю большую картинку в ImageView. Приложение загружается, работает, но картинка просто не отображается.

Пробовал загружать картинки поменьше - всё работает. если загружать эту же картинку в WebView, то она тоже отображается.

В чем подвох?

Comment: Большая это сколько? В логе чтонить пишется? Ну а вообще если большая картинка не отображается, то по моему очевидно что надо её уменьшить, а потом уже отображать. К сожалению ImageView сам это делать не умеет.

Comment: Картинка 500х7633 в логе вроде ниче такого не пишется

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подвох в том что на надо загружать большие картинки непосредственно в ImageView, он на это не рассчитан. Надо сначала уменьшить, как это сделать описано например [тут](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html). Но ваша картинка это вообще полотно какое то (соотношение сторон 1 к 15), его бы для начала нарезать надо имхо. В общем прочитайте [офф гайд по эффектиному отображению картинок](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html).

Comment: Спасибо, буду читать))